# How do I specialize my class template to fewer arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class template I am trying to specialize for five different cases:

```
template<size_t Number, typename T>
class Foo {};

template<typename T>
class Foo {}; // I get template argument errors here

template<size_t Number, typename T, size_t Size>
class Foo<Number, T[Size]> {};

template<size_t Number, typename T>
class Foo<Number, T[]> {};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T[]> {};  // I get template argument errors here too
```

Is this possible?

Comment: this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/12bb75c9-dfec-42f5-8b55-b669cc56ad76/entry/c__e6_a8_a1_e6_9d_bf__e7_a9_b6_e7_ab_9f_e4_bb_80_e4_b9_88_e6_98_af_e7_89_b9_e5_8c_96?lang=en) my help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this interface, where a `Number` of -1 fails at compile time based on an implementation detail in my class. Such that you must specify a valid `Number`.

```
template<typename T, size_t Number = -1>
class Foo {};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, -1> {};

template<typename T, size_t Size, size_t Number>
class Foo<T[Size], Number> {};

template<typename T, size_t Number>
class Foo<T[], Number> {};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T[], -1> {};
```

Answer (score 4):

No. Instead, you can create a partial specialization. For the first attempted specialization, what do you want for Number? Then fill it in: `template <typename T> class Foo<3, T> {};`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/
you can see the template specification section and get a clear example..

Hope that help